# Django admin search/filter functionality as a page table

Tags: django, django-admin

I was wondering if there is a way to use the power of Django Admin's filtering/ordering/paginating/search capabilities in a regular view.

What I mean is that I have a model, some fields on it. I'd like to have a "search" form, where fields would be defined much like using admin.ModelAdmin. User would be able to search (using provided fields), filter by values, paginate through pages of result table etc. All that without minimal amount of work on my part, eg. just configuration which fields should be used in the form. Something like this:

```
class SchoolAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'name', )
    list_display_links = ('name', )
    search_fields = ('name', )
    list_filter = ('type', )
```

Is there something like this available? Or do I have to code it myself?

Edit:

Features I require from such a plugin/application are:

1. Display data as a table
2. Sorting by columns
3. Filtering (eg. "show only rows that has X = Y")
4. Searching by columns
5. Optionally configuration similar to ModelAdmin style

Alasdair's [django-tables2](https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-tables2)  only matches 1st and 2nd conditions.

Comment: What is the current status in 1.7?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The django functionality you mention isn't really reusable in custom views as of Django 1.3.  There was recently some discussion on the django-developers group about [splitting out admin functionality](http://groups.google.com/group/django-developers/browse_thread/thread/54f51dbf63d242d1/89306dad7abd4cca?) to make it reusable.

I have come across two projects that might be useful to you, [django-tables2](https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-tables2) and [django-filter](https://github.com/alex/django-filter). They both offer slightly different things, I think you're looking for a mixture of the two.

## django-tables2

> django-tables2 simplifies the task of turning sets of data into HTML tables. It has native support for pagination and sorting. It does for HTML tables what django.forms does for HTML forms

## django-filter

> Django-filter is a reusable Django application for allowing users to filter
>   queryset dynamically.  It requires Python 2.4 or higher.  For usage and
>   installation instructions consult the docs directory.
>
> Django-filter can be used for generating interfaces similar to the Django
>   admin's `list_filter` interface.  It has an API very similar to Django's
>   `ModelForms`.

Comment: Yeah, I do not want to reuse ModelAdmin, I want something for public views, that has the capabilities of ModelAdmin.

Comment: django-filter is what I was looking for! Right now I'm using it with django-pagination, but will check if it works with django-tables2 as well.

Answer (score 2):

To extend on Alasdair's answer, I added a simple module that adds simple filtering to django-tables2. See https://github.com/benjiec/django-tables2-simplefilter.