# Use Django list_display ModelAdmin in mainsite?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-views, django-modeladmin

I've got a reasonably good AdminSite working for my app (very much a data-entry / dashboard-style app for scientists working in a collaborative team).

The users have a bunch of experiments they can sort, filter, edit, etc. This works well in the AdminSite.

It seems like the best practice (since I'd like to move to building more custom views/reports) is not to hack the AdminSite to bits ('the admin is not your app').

The users like the functionality of the table list - in particular being able to filter easily, sort by multiple columns.

What is the easiest way of re-implementing this with minimal code? Do I have to reimplement the sorting and filtering logic from scratch myself?

Comment: `ModelAdmin` classes aren't really reusable outside of the admin. I wrote [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999541/django-admin-search-filter-functionality-as-a-page-table/7999682#7999682) several years ago, but the situation is still pretty similar today.